# Disable automatic activity email to assignee

Tags: activities

Is there a way to disable the activity summary email that is automatically sent out to the activity assignee?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Go to Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Preferences

Uncheck the "Notify Activity Assignees" box

Comment: This is really useful and note that you can exclude certain types of activity.  We have a couple of custom activities that only need completing if a process proceeds to the next stage.  We can assign the actitvity so we have a record of it, but a copy of this does not get sent out.